# Call different method apart from doGet or doPost in sling servlet

Tags: java, servlets, sling

I am new to Sling framework. Is there any way we can call different methods.

For ex - on Page I have add,delete, edit button so apart from creating three files i can create three methods(add, delete,update) in same file.

Please suggest.

I tried by changing the method name

```
@Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = { "getData" })
```

But it is not working

```
@Service
@Properties({
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = { "getData" }),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = { "GET" })
     })
public class getData extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
```

Answer (score 3):

The `SlingAllMethodsServlet` will support any of the valid HTTP verbs as methods and in response to a request will call the appropriate `do` method.  For instance, in response to a `PUT` request the `doPut` method will be called.

In your case if you wanted your servlet to support both getting data and creating new data, you would want to allow methods `GET` and `POST` and implement the `doGet` and `doPost` methods.

```
@Service
@Properties( {
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = { "/getData" } ),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = { "GET", "POST" } )
    } )
public class DataServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) { ... }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) { ... }

}
```

To add delete and edit support as well you would simply need to support the `DELETE` and `PUT` HTTP verbs along with implementing the `doDelete` and `doPut` methods in your servlet.

A tangentially related note - by using the [`@SlingServlet` annotation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html#registering-a-servlet-using-java-annotations) in place of the @Service and @Component annotations you can shorten the code a bit and get better autocompletion and documentation support.

Comment: And note that it's better to avoid registering servlets with sling.servlet.paths. As per https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html , creating a resource at the desired path, with a resource type that maps to a servlet, provides the same result in most cases while taking advantage of more Sling built-in features including access control.